# A faster way of comparing two lists of point-tuples?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists (which may or may not be the same length). In each list, are a series of tuples of two points (basically X, Y values).

I am comparing the two lists against each other to find two points with similar point values. I have tried list comprehension techniques, but it got really confusing with the nested tuples inside of the lists and I couldn't get it to work.

Is this the best (fastest) way of doing this? I feel like there might be a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Say I have two lists:

```
pointPairA = [(2,1), (4,8)]
pointPairB = [(3,2), (10,2), (4,2)]
```

And then an empty list for storing the pairs and a tolerance value to store only matched pairs

```
matchedPairs = []
tolerance = 2
```

And then this loop that unpacks the tuples, compares the difference, and adds them to the matchedPairs list to indicate a match.

```
for pointPairA in pointPairListA:
    for pointPairB in pointPairListB:
        ## Assign the current X,Y values for each pair
        pointPairA_x, pointPairA_y = pointPairA
        pointPairB_x, pointPairB_x = pointPairB

        ## Get the difference of each set of points
        xDiff = abs(pointPairA_x - pointPairB_x)
        yDiff = abs(pointPairA1_y - pointPairB_y)

        if xDiff < tolerance and yDiff < tolerance:
            matchedPairs.append((pointPairA, pointPairB))
```

That would result in matchedPairs looking like this, with tuples of both point tuples inside:

```
[( (2,1), (3,2) ), ( (2,1), (4,2) )]
```

Comment: If you can use "distance" for instead of a square for the tolerance, you could use complex numbers instead of tuples eg. `[2+1j, 4+8j]`. You can then compare the `abs(pt1-pt2)` with the tolerance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here pointpairA is the single list and pointpairB would be one of the list of 20k

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

pointPairA = [(2,1), (4,8)]
pointPairB = [(3,2), (10,2), (4,2)]
tolerance = 2

dA = defaultdict(list)
tolrange = range(-tolerance, tolerance+1)
for pA, dx, dy in product(pointPairA, tolrange, tolrange):
    dA[pA[0]+dx,pA[1]+dy].append(pA)

# you would have a loop here though the 20k lists
matchedPairs = [(pA, pB) for pB in pointPairB for pA in dA[pB]]  

print matchedPairs
```

Answer (score 2):

If these lists are large, I would suggest finding a faster algorithm...

I would start by sorting both lists of pairs by the sum of the (x,y) in the pair.  (Because two points can be close only if their sums are close.)

For any point in the first list, that will severely limit the range you need to search in the second list.  Keep track of a "sliding window" on the second list, corresponding to the elements whose sums are within `2*tolerance` of the sum of the current element of the first list.  (Actually, you only need to keep track of the start of the sliding window...)

Assuming `tolerance` is reasonably small, this should convert your O(n^2) operation into O(n log n).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that, the lists aren't large at all. In fact, currently, they'll never be more than 15 tuples long, and most of them are ~14 long.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
[(pa, pb) for pa in pointPairA for pb in pointPairB \
          if abs(pa[0]-pb[0]) <= tolerance and abs(pa[1]-pb[1]) <= tolerance]
```

Slightly much faster than your loop:

```
(for 1 million executions)

>>> (list comprehension).timeit()
2.1963138580322266 s

>>> (your method).timeit()
2.454944133758545 s
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, thanks for that example. That's exactly what I needed for the one liner. Slightly faster, and I'm sure that'll add up: I have one list which I compare against 20k others.

Comment: @STH, Since you are comparing one list with 20k others it may make sense to spend some time creating a dict or set from the one list to allow really fast lookups for the 20k others. Are the values always integers? For a tolerance of 2, the dict would be 25x the size of the list, but the 20k comparisons would then be O(N)

Comment: @gnibbler you mean make the first list the dictionary or set, and not the 20k others, correct? The values will always be integers. The 20k lists are stored in a MySQL database after being pickled.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know of my speed difference here. After converting to the one liner, the speed of the entire function being ran once was 1.80s, and is now 0.87s.

Comment: @STH, yes, I have provided this in an answer now